# Estoy empezando con python y no entiendo una cosa. Ayuda

Tags: python

Estoy siguiendo un curso para principiantes.
En el siguiente ejemplo no entiendo el uso de x% en la linea

> t.pencolor(colors[x%len(family)]) # Rotate through the colors

Si alguien me lo puede explicar, se lo agradecería.

Dejo aquí  el programa entero.

```
# SpiralFamily.py - prints a colorful spiral of names
import turtle     # Set up turtle graphics
t = turtle.Pen()  
turtle.bgcolor("black")
colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "orange",
        "purple", "white", "brown", "gray", "pink" ]
family = []       # Set up an empty list for family names
# Ask for the first name
name = turtle.textinput("My family",
                        "Enter a name, or just hit [ENTER] to end:")
# Keep asking for names
while name != "":
    # Add their name to the family list
    family.append(name)
    # Ask for another name, or end
    name = turtle.textinput("My family",
                        "Enter a name, or just hit [ENTER] to end:")
# Draw a spiral of the names on the screen
for x in range(100):
    t.pencolor(colors[x%len(family)]) # Rotate through the colors
    t.penup()                         # Don't draw the regular spiral lines
    t.forward(x*4)                    # Just move the turtle on the screen
    t.pendown()                       # Draw the next family member's name
    t.write(family[x%len(family)], font = ("Arial", int((x+4)/4), "bold") )
    t.left(360/len(family) + 2)         # Turn left for our spiral
```

Comment: Para que la pregunta pueda ayudar a futuros usuarios, deberias especificar lo que estas preguntando en el titulo. Por ejemplo, puedes titularla "¿Qué significa este simbolo/operador en codigo Python?".

Comment: Gracias lo tendré presente.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

operador modulo/residuo (resto) `%` el cual existe en casi todos los lenguajes, básicamente es una división entre números enteros y retorna el residuo. **Siempre y cuando el numerador sea mayor o igual que el denominador**, el residuo siempre estará entre 0 y 9 de forma que al hacer

```
x%len(family) // retorna entre 0 y 9
```

Utiliza esto para asegurar que siempre le de un número "aleatorio" entre 0 y 9 para acceder al arreglo `colors` que es de tamaño 10, de esta forma siempre estará escogiendo un indice al azar que no se saldrá de los limites del arreglo.

PD: `len(array)` retorna el tamaño de un arreglo

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta. Ahora lo veo claro. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.Un 10 de respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El operador `%` te devuelve el resto de una división, así por ejemplo `x%2` devolverá 0 si `x` es par, o `1` si es impar.

En general, el resto de la divisón `A%B` será un número comprendido entre `0` y `B-1`.

Es muy típico utilizar esta operación para asegurarte de que tu número nunca se sale de un cierto rango. Por ejemplo, si quieres tener un contador que vaya subiendo de uno en uno, pero que si llega a 50 vuelva a comenzar por cero, una forma razonable de hacerlo sería:

```
contador = contador + 1
if contador == 50:
   contador = 0
```

Pero otra forma más breve, usando el operador `%` sería:

```
contador = (contador + 1) % 50
```

Fíjate que en en cuanto el contador exceda 50, al quedarse con el resto de su división entre 50 "vuelve a empezar por cero". Esto funciona incluso si en lugar de incrementarlo de 1 en 1 lo incrementas de cualquier otra forma. Siempre que se pase de 50 "entra otra vez por debajo" (53 se convertiría en 3, etc.)

Este uso es el que se le da también para acceder a diferentes elementos de un array de forma cíclica, es decir, que una vez que hayamos elegido el último elemento, volvamos a comenzar por el primero.

De eso trata precisamente el código de tu ejemplo (**que por cierto tiene un bug**, pues en lugar de `len(family)` debería usar `len(colors)`):

```
colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "orange",
        "purple", "white", "brown", "gray", "pink" ]
# ...
for x in range(100):
    t.pencolor(colors[x%len(colors)])
```

Fíjate que la `x` varía entre 0 y 100, y en cada iteración queremos usar un color diferente de la lista `colors`, en la que sólo hay 10 elementos. Si ponemos simplemente `colors[x]`, cuando la `x` llegue al valor 10 estaríamos salíendonos de la lista (pues sus índices van de 0 a 9). Con el truco del operador `%`, aseguramos que estamos accediendo siempre a elementos válidos (entre `0` y `len(colors)-1`).

De este modo se accede a los colores en secuencia, de forma cíclica (una vez se alcance el `"pink"`, el siguiente sería de nuevo `"red"`).